# "As you're subscribed now so you'll receive"

Tags: grammaticality, conjunctions

Is starting the sentence with "as" appropriate?

For example:

> As you're subscribed now so you'll receive...

Answer (score 3):

Starting a sentence with "as" is perfectly appropriate. What is not appropriate is your starting the sentence with "as" *and* then having the "so" later on. Both are conjunctions, both express a cause–effect relationship between two clauses, and crucially, both are connecting *the same* two clauses. As a result, the sentence is ungrammatical as stated. You have to pick exactly one and be done with it:

> - As you're subscribed now, you'll receive...
> - You're subscribed now, so you'll receive...

Do note that the ellipsis is always three periods, not two or four.

Comment: A correct ellipsis is not three periods either. An ellipsis is a single character. Three periods are only used where the char … can not be used. But nowadays the web is pretty good at supporting those characters.

Comment: Right on, thank you for that. Regulars will know I'm the first one to use proper Unicode characters. I just didn't want to make things too complicated. Three periods are still better than nothing.

Comment: Agreed, using at least the proper amount of periods is better then writing arbitrary things.